# Adding line break to XML file in ubuntu

Tags: xml, ubuntu, line-breaks, gedit

I saved an XML file onto my ubuntu machine. However when I try to open it with gedit everything is shown with no line breaks. My question is simple, how can I add line breaks to my XML file?

Cheers,

Ch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML file is in RAW format.

Formatting it more palpable and human readable is possible with `xmlindent`.

```
sudo apt-get install xmlindent
```

and then apply it like:

```
cat file.xml | xmlindent -f -t > output.xml
```

You could omit the `-f` and `-t` options.

- `-t` stands for "use tabulator instead of spaces" and
- `-f` stands for adding a new line on empty tags like `<tag />`.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Accepting my answer would be a further proof of your thankfulness ;-)